# iterating over yeardatescalendar repeats dates

Tags: python

Why are some dates in the output repeated and is there any (clean) way to modify the following script to fix it? I wouldn't want to put the output in a list and find unique dates or anything like that. Wondering if the loop itself can be modified.

```
import calendar

c = calendar.Calendar()
for item in c.yeardatescalendar(2014):
    for i1 in item:
        for i2 in i1:
            for i3 in i2:
                if 'Fri' in i3.ctime():
                    print i3
```

Here is the output, notice some of the dates are repeated:

```
2014-01-03
2014-01-10
2014-01-17
2014-01-24
2014-01-31
2014-01-31
2014-02-07
2014-02-14
2014-02-21
2014-02-28
2014-02-28
2014-03-07
2014-03-14
2014-03-21
2014-03-28
2014-04-04
2014-04-04
2014-04-11
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue stems from the fact that python's idea of a month/year etc. always includes full weeks. Therefore, the list for february might in fact have dates from january and etc. In fact, some dates from 2015 happened to be in the list for 2014. The only way to mitigate this way is to accumulates fridays in another data structure that eliminates duplicates.

An easy way to do this is a set. A set is a collection of items that does not have duplicates but has no order. If you want to know more, take a look at the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set). Therefore, we will create a set of fridays, sort them, and then print them out to get the desired effect.

Here's the code:

```
import calendar

cal = calendar.Calendar()

fridays = set() # Constructs a new, empty set

# build a list of months, which are a list of weeks, etc.
months = [cal.monthdatescalendar(2014, month) for month in range(1, 13)]
for month in months:
    for week in month:
        for day in week:
            if day.weekday() == 4 and day.year == 2014:
                fridays.add(day)

for friday in sorted(fridays): # iterate through sorted fridays
    print friday
```

And the results:

```
2014-01-03
2014-01-10
2014-01-17
2014-01-24
2014-01-31
2014-02-07
2014-02-14
2014-02-21
2014-02-28
2014-03-07
2014-03-14
2014-03-21
2014-03-28
2014-04-04
2014-04-11
...
```